# Referrer to get previous page it isn't working always

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My problem is Referrer to get previous page it is not working right for example if i open my  PHP website from google

document.referrer

working right and i get google link but if i open my website from Bing
referrer returns null . I don't know why ? my web site is https . and i need to get from where user come to my website so any body know the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **should not** rely on referrer, it's a just a HTTP header which may not be included in the request. Here are some cases where `document.referer` will be empty:

- enter site directly
- enter site from bookmarks
- browser settings
- redirect from http <-> https
- etc.

Comment: thanks for reply MR : @vitozev so did you know if there is alternative

Comment: What you're tryng to do? Btw, you can upvote the answer if was helpful for you.

Comment: i want to know from where users come from to my website from google or bing .... etc and i tried to know that by referrer

Comment: Actually the only way to get the site user comes from is using referrals. So, you should use them, but in some cases your statistical data will be not accurate.